# SemanticImport mis-interprets CSV

Tags: import, dataset

`SemanticImport` misinterprets rows with trailing blanks. Note the commas in the 2nd column:

SemanticImport["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ati-pfGwn22sdGt1T3E4S3NFYWxmQXY2ZUJ0MmhXd2c&output=csv", 
 Delimiters -> ",", HeaderLines -> 1]

[image]

`Import[...,Delimiters->","]//Dataset` doesn't recognize the header line identifiers as keys.

(Note Google has deprecated csv web pub of gsheets)

Answer (score 8):

This is one workaround:

```
csv = Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ati-pfGwn22sdGt1T3E4S3NFYWxmQXY2ZUJ0MmhXd2c&output=csv", "CSV"];

header = First[csv]

data = Rest[csv];

Dataset[
 AssociationThread[header -> #] & /@ data
]
```

Comment: That's the solution I've been using to build key-value structures before Dataset, except as a list of Rules, hence only Thread (Association@Thread = AssociationThread). But I meant a set of options for SemanticImport?

Comment: @alancalvitti Sorry, I didn't re-read your question, and I remembered that you asked "Alternatively how to cast to `Dataset` from good ol' `Import`?"

Comment: @alancalvitti Here's a solution that seems nicer than `AssociationThread`: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/290815?p_p_auth=u7fX6KQc  (still not an answer to your `SemanticImport` question, just an improvement on this).

Answer (score 5):

This is a good test set. I'm feeding this to the primary developer on `SemanticImport`, hopefully we can fix this for 10.0.1 (we've already improved `SemanticImport` a lot since the release branch).